# How to figure out the "time" of trigger firing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to get all properties for the particular trigger. 
The last thing, that I can't find is the information about time of firing:

For DML: FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF

For DDL: FOR | AFTER.

In the worst case I can get this info from sys.sql_modules table by parsing definition column for particular trigger.

But I still hope, that this information stored in one of system tables.

Answer (score 0):

It may not totally suffice your question but the following query contains the cached time and the last execution time of the trigger. Most of the properties of the trigger are covered.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. Need to figure out when trigger will fire, by DEFINITION. It should be FOR, AFTER or INSTEAD OF of DML triggers.